# Split a column into multiple rows based on multiple delimiters in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, split

I have following table in postgres 11.

```
col1
a;b;c
d/e/f
g and h
i with k
l + m
```

I would like to split this table based on certain delimiters (/,+,;,and,with]). The desired output is:

```
col1          col2
a;b;c         a
a;b;c         b
a;b;c         c
d/e/f         d
d/e/f         e
d/e/f         f
g and h       g
g and h       h
i with k      i
i with k      k
l + m         l
l + m         m
```

I am trying out below query.

```
select distinct * from table t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_ARRAY(t.col1, '\s+[/|+|;|and|with]\s+')) s(col2)
```

Comment: Replace `[/|+|;|and|with]` with `(?:[/+;]|and|with)`, a grouping construct. `[...]` is a bracket expression that only matches a single char defined inside it.

Comment: What is the purpose of adding '?:'

Comment: Non-capturing groups are a natural choice when the value matched by a grouping is not going to be retrieved/used later.

Comment: Actually split by ; is not working..

Comment: Maybe that is due to spaces? Try `\s*(?:[/+;]|and|with)\s*`, or `[/+;]|\s+(?:and|with)\s+`

Comment: So, does anything work as expected?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Space was the issue.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[/+;]|\s+(?:and|with)\s+
\s*(?:[/+;]|and|with)\s*
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/p3oPPN/1/) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/p3oPPN/2).

**Details**

- `[/+;]` - a `+`, `/` or `;` char
  -`|` - or
- `\s+(?:and|with)\s+` - an `and` or `with` words enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `\s*(?:[/+;]|and|with)\s*` matches a `/`, `+`, `;` or `and` or `with` strings enclosed with 0 or more whitespace chars.

Note `(?:...)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) that is a natural choice when the value matched by a grouping construct is not going to be retrieved/used later.